# iOS9 does not load insecure resources from a secure page

Tags: ios, objective-c, iphone, ios9

Not able to load the insecure resources in secure page in iOS9 everything working fine before iOS9.
Tried with NSThirdPartyExceptionAllowsInsecureHTTPLoads but no luck.

Trying the same in webview

Answer (score 0):

iOS 9 introduced the App Transport Security. This mean that any connection made of https should be TLS1.2 or higher.

You can turn ATS off for legacy system add `NSAppTransportSecurity` to you info.plist a dictionary and then add the key `NSAllowsArbitraryLoads` with bool value `YES`

Answer (score 0):

You can try to add the following to your Info.plist:

```
<key>NSAppTransportSecurity</key>
<dict>
    <key>NSAllowsArbitraryLoads</key>
    <true/>
</dict>
```

Answer (score 0):

You have to add an entry into plist. just like in below image.

[image]